# WP upload/select image , isn't this a security issue?

Tags: uploads, security

If in image upload frame I select a zip 
http://prntscr.com/6ypjlv, it does not show it in list of files but it is up
http://prntscr.com/6ypjvp

shouldn't we only be able to upload image types if library is set to images ?

```
    thz_media_frame = wp.media.frames.thz_media_frame = wp.media({

        className: 'media-frame thz-media-frame',
        frame: 'select',
        multiple: false,
        title: thz_image.title,
        library: {
            type: 'image' // images only
        }

    });
```

that upload folder is easy to guess so anyone who wants to take advantage of it could simply upload a file and go have fun. I am sure there is a possibility of media upload restrictions but I would expect if I say upload image , that user can upload only images and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Have no idea were that code snippet comes from but security for uploaded files should be addressed in three steps

1. Upload permission should be restricted only to people you trust (assuming you are the admin/owner), and security is just part of the reason (think someone uploading porn to a church site)
2. You should not let the php interpreter execute anything in the uploads directory. This will prevent people uploading and then executing rouge php scripts on your server.
3. Any file which is not of an approved extension serve as a simple octet stream. Configured properly this will prevent people uploading JS and using them for cookie theft.  A twist on it is to serve uploaded files from a different domain.

How to implement steps 2 and 3 depends on type of web sever you use.

Comment: that is my code for calling wp.media frame , but same code is in default image option that allows only images